# Performant way of concatenating 3 byte arrays and base64 encode them

Tags: c#, .net, performance, .net-core

Given this simple code:

```cs
private static string GetEncryptedContent(byte[] arrayA, byte[] arrayB, byte[] arrayC)
{
    var concatenatedArray = new byte[arrayB.Length + arrayC.Length + arrayA.Length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(arrayB, 0, concatenatedArray, 0, arrayB.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(arrayC, 0, concatenatedArray, arrayB.Length, arrayC.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(arrayA, 0, concatenatedArray, arrayC.Length + arrayB.Length,
        arrayA.Length);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(concatenatedArray);
}
```

Is there a way to base64 encode the byte arrays without allocating a new byte array with the size of a+b+C?

Comment: Well it's not *very* hard to write your own base64 encoder, if you really, really need to. But I'd start by analysing whether the performance hit here is actually significant in your specific context.

Comment: You're assuming that allocating a byte array and concatenation is particularly expensive. It isn't (c.f.: `StringBuilder`). Though if you're doing this in a tight-loop you should consider using a reusable buffer - which at least saves you the allocation, but as _all_ overloads of `ToBase64String` require a contiguous input (as either `Byte[]` or `ReadOnlySpan<Byte>`) there's no way around the concatenation, unless you build your own Base64 encoder.

Comment: @JonSkeet to be fair, an unnecessary additional and potentially large `byte[]` alloc is absolutely something I'd eliminate simply on principle

Comment: The result of base64 is longer than the original data, so you definitely need a larger buffer to save the final result, or can your result be passed out as a stream?

Comment: @MarcGravell if OP dealing with such a big arrays the resulting string is likely allocated on LOH... At this point (if performance *actually* matters) they are likely better off to either dump result directly to some real stream (obviously not `MemoryStream`) or come up with some chunked-in-memory stream/string storage...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov true, and in that scenario there are tools for bypassing encoding - `System.Buffers.Text.Base64` for example; but: half of something bad is still less bad ;P

Answer (score 6):

If the arrays are relatively large, you can *rent* an (oversized) array using `ArrayPool<byte>.Shared`, copy to the rented array, then use the overload of `ToBase64String` that takes offset+count, using offset 0 and the length of the known data as the count. Then return the leased array back to the pool.

If the arrays are know to be tiny, you can use `stackalloc` to create a `Span<byte>`, using the `ToBase64String` overload that takes `ReadOnlySpan<byte>`.